# Modify request data after validation and before sending to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request

I am using Laravel's FormRequest for validation to make my code clean in controller and after validation, I want to add some data to request and then save it. So, I was just looking for a solution so that I do not have to add data to request in controller If just after validation in the same file there could be the extra function for modifying data and send to controller. It would have been better.

Comment: Try the [after validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#after-validation-hook)

Comment: why do you even want to do such a thing? can you explain with an example?

Comment: In controller after validation I had to add some data to request such as $request->request->add(['is_archived' => 1]); so I wanted that if from FormRequest file which I have created for validation of a particular function after doing such thing in FormRequest I will not have to add any data to request. for cleaner code the request will come validated and modified from single FormRequest file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do something with request after it validated, you can use [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#after-validation-hook), as apokryfos suggested.

But I think it is a bit more convinient to put that hook inside of your `FormRequest` descendant class.

**Ancestor:**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AncestorRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        return parent::getValidatorInstance()->after(function ($validator) {
            $this->after($validator);
        });
    }

    protected function after($validator)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Descendant:**

```
class DescendantRequest extends AncestorRequest
{
    ...

    public function after($validator)
    {
        // do your things
    }
}
```

P. S. This solution I am using in Laravel 5.2. [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-how-to-use-after-method-on-form-request?page=1) you can find more options.

Comment: Just wanted to ask in after method of AncestorRequest class I can do this so why to create a new DescendantRequest?

Comment: yes, you can, but then if you want to add new request with after hook, you should add `getValidatorInstance` inside you new request. again. in case i have described in answer you write this method just in ancestor class

Comment: Thanks, Got this :)

Comment: @SubhashDiwakar in the end, how did you get to add some data to request inside `function after`? I tried like this `request()->merge(['key' => 'value']);` but the input `key` doesn't appear in controller: `$request->input('key'); // returns empty`.

Comment: got it: `$this->merge(['key' => 'value']);`. Actually doing both way are correct, `request()->merge(['key' => 'value']);` makes the input available in controller through `request()->input('key');` and `$this->merge(['key' => 'value']);` makes the input available in controller through `$request->input('key');`. I use both at the same time, because I put it in a trait to reuse it, I want to make sure it will work in both ways, no matter if controller access inputs through `request()` or `$request` (I often use both).

Comment: @cawecoy I did created a new method in FormRequest file I created for validation. I named it dbColumns(). after the validation is done, then from controller I call this function $request->dbColumns() and I get the filtered data that I can add into DB